# Run command on iOS app from a webapp/server?

Tags: ios, iphone, cron, remote-access

Assuming I have permission from the user, is it possible for my server to trigger an action on my app on my user's phone? Does the phone have to be unlocked?

I want to make calls to the keychain API using both crons and manual requests.

Comment: Your server can send a "silent push" to trigger your app. Access to the keychain may not be available, depending on the keychain items protection level and the lock state of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your app on the client, then you can do anything that is in the capabilities of the application.  Are you asking for a hosted webview in your application?

Answer (score 0):

**If the phone is unlocked and the app is running**, then yes you can have a two-way connection to a server, using either the [TCP protocol](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) or the [WebSocket protocol](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket). Otherwise, no.